# Getting Text Instead of RTF/Objects from PHPExcel Reading

Tags: php, mongodb, phpexcel

I am working a project where I am using the PHPExcel library to do some things.  I ran into my first problem today.  Reading/Writing to and from Excel work great, but then I was going to start taking things out from an Excel sheet and then do some entry into Mongo.  I basically read something into an array from Excel, then try and save that array into Mongo by `$collection->insert($array);`

I got an exception telling me it couldn't insert anything with a zero character key.  I did a `var_dum()` on my array to see where in the world it was getting a blank key at, and this is what the dump produced.

```
array(10) 
{ 
    ["um"]=> string(2) "EA" 
    ["desc"]=> string(37) "FRAME WELDMENT, NITRATE REMOVAL TANKS" 
    ["vws_num"]=> NULL 
    ["part_num"]=> string(10) "SD-0408-01" 
    ["manufac"]=> object(PHPExcel_RichText)#665 (1) 
    { 
        ["_richTextElements" : "PHPExcel_RichText" : private]=> array(3) 
        { 
            [0]=> object(PHPExcel_RichText_TextElement)#184 (1) 
            { 
                ["_text":"PHPExcel_RichText_TextElement":private]=> string(23) "VEOLIA WATER SOLUTIONS " 
            } 
            [1]=> object(PHPExcel_RichText_Run)#179 (2) 
            { 
                ["_font":"PHPExcel_RichText_Run":private]=> object(PHPExcel_Style_Font)#183 (12) 
                { 
                    ["_name":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> string(5) "SWGDT" 
                    ["_size":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> string(2) "10" 
                    ["_bold":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_italic":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_superScript":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_subScript":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_underline":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> string(4) "none" 
                    ["_strikethrough":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_color":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> object(PHPExcel_Style_Color)#186 (4) 
                    { 
                        ["_argb":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> string(8) "FF000000" 
                        ["_isSupervisor":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> bool(false) 
                        ["_parent":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> NULL 
                        ["_parentPropertyName":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> NULL 
                    } 
                    ["_parentPropertyName":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> NULL 
                    ["_isSupervisor":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_parent":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> NULL 
                } 
                ["_text":"PHPExcel_RichText_TextElement":private]=> string(1) " " 
            } 
            [2]=> object(PHPExcel_RichText_Run)#182 (2) 
            { 
                ["_font":"PHPExcel_RichText_Run":private]=> object(PHPExcel_Style_Font)#189 (12) 
                { 
                    ["_name":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> string(14) "Century Gothic" 
                    ["_size":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> string(2) "10" 
                    ["_bold":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_italic":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_superScript":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_subScript":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_underline":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> string(4) "none" 
                    ["_strikethrough":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_color":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> object(PHPExcel_Style_Color)#188 (4) 
                    { 
                        ["_argb":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> string(8) "FF000000" 
                        ["_isSupervisor":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> bool(false) 
                        ["_parent":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> NULL 
                        ["_parentPropertyName":"PHPExcel_Style_Color":private]=> NULL 
                    } 
                    ["_parentPropertyName":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> NULL 
                    ["_isSupervisor":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> bool(false) 
                    ["_parent":"PHPExcel_Style_Font":private]=> NULL 
                } 
                ["_text":"PHPExcel_RichText_TextElement":private]=> string(14) "& TECHNOLOGIES" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    ["vendor"]=> NULL 
    ["unit_price"]=> NULL 
    ["list_price"]=> NULL 
    ["multiplier"]=> NULL 
    ["times_req"]=> float(1) 
}
```

Why is my `"manufac"` key holding a crazy insane looking PHPExcel Object?  I am retrieving each cell's contents as

`$array[$rowIndex][$col] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();`

I know the particular cell of the Excel sheet has a new line character in it, would that be it?  Or is this telling me there is some type of weird format being placed on that cell?

I am just wanting the text value from this cell, like all the other ones have given me...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `crazy insane looking PHPExcel Object` is a Rich Text object, a cell value that contains formatted text.

You can test if a cell contains a Rich Text object using:

```
if ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet->getCell('A1')->getValue() instanceof PHPExcel_RichText)
```

and extract the plain text content from the cell using

```
$plaintext = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet->getCell('A1')
    ->getValue()->getPlainText();
```

Comment: I believe this used to work, but there is a bug in 1.7.8
I submitted a bug report here - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/19540

Comment: If getCell()->getValue() ever returned plaintext instead of a rich text object, then that was a bug, meaning that it was impossible ever to get existing rich text in order to modify it without simply converting it to plain text. Returning the rich text object is correct behaviour. However, getCalculatedValue should return plaintext

Comment: Modified the getCalculatedValue() method to return the text content of richtext objects rather than the object - pushed to the github repository ready for version 1.7.9